# unable to execute sql query in teradata using teradatasql python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata, teradatasql

I want to run a SQL query in Teradata using the Teradata SQL python module. I am getting the below error.

Code:

```
import teradatasql
conn='{"host":"hostname","logmech":"KRB5"}'
cxnn=teradatasql.connect(conn)
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: please attach the image within the question than having it as a hyperlink

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967811/connecting-to-teradata-using-teradatasql-module-in-python Perhaps , It will help you.

Comment: @Kulasangar It says wee need 10 reputation to embed images.

Comment: @user11225404 It didn''t work

Comment: Now you have 10 reputation ;)

Comment: Pasting the error as text would have been a lot easier, and less blurry.

Comment: For KRB5, you need either to already have a Kerberos ticket or to supply credentials using "logdata" parameter, in the form user@realm@@password

Comment: Kerberos authentication is already present and it is working from other servers. @Fred

Comment: Major status 0x70000 is "credentials unavailable". On the server in question, do klist / kinit function normally from the command line?